# returning a loop output to a function

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am pretty new to JavaScript, but I have been tasked with creating a script that will figure the monthly payment for a car loan. I made a function that accepts the inputs for amount of the loan, length of the loan, and interest rate, so that I can calculate the specific monthly payment. I want to also be able to show the user the monthly payment if they get a loan for a longer length of time like 36, 48, or 60 months. I used a loop to change the variable for loan length to do this, but I can not figure out how to get the function to accept the different lengths that the loop created. Maybe I am going about this all wrong.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function payment(monthly_interest_rate, loan_amount, loan_length) {
  var base = Math.pow(1 + monthly_interest_rate, loan_length);
  var payment = loan_amount * monthly_interest_rate / (1 - (1 / base));
  return payment;
}


var vehicle_price = parseInt(prompt("How much does the vehicle cost?"));
var down_payment = parseInt(prompt("How much is the down payment?"));
var interest_rate = parseFloat(prompt("What is the interest rate?"));
var loan_amount = vehicle_price - down_payment;
var monthly_interest_rate = interest_rate / 1200;
var loan_length = parseInt(prompt("How many months is the loan?"));

document.write("Vehicle price: $" + vehicle_price + "<br>");
document.write("Down payment: $" + down_payment + "<br>");
document.write("Interest rate: " + interest_rate + "%" + "<br>");
document.write("Loan Amount: $ " + loan_amount + "<br>");


document.write("Number of months: " + "<br>");
for (loan_length = 24; loan_length < 61; loan_length += 12) {
  document.write(loan_length + "<br>");
}


var monthly_payment = payment(monthly_interest_rate, loan_amount, loan_length).toFixed(2);



document.write("<br>" + "Monthly payment");
document.write("<br>" + "$" + monthly_payment);
```

```html
<h1>Loan Calculator</h1>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you create the html and use .value and .innerHTML to set the values - I created a snippet and moved stuff around for you

Comment: Id look at knockout for databinding your html, instead of writing loads of document write tags. Just a thought! Well worth the time investment to learn it :)

Comment: shouldn't you call payment function with loan_length in the loop and write the result instead of just the loan_length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```js
function payment(monthly_interest_rate, loan_amount, loan_length) {
  var base = Math.pow(1 + monthly_interest_rate, loan_length);
 return loan_amount * monthly_interest_rate / (1 - (1 / base));
}


var vehicle_price = 1000
var down_payment = 200
var interest_rate = 1.5
var loan_amount = vehicle_price - down_payment;
var monthly_interest_rate = interest_rate / 1200;
var loan_length = 12

document.write("Vehicle price: $" + vehicle_price + "<br>");
document.write("Down payment: $" + down_payment + "<br>");
document.write("Interest rate: " + interest_rate + "%" + "<br>");
document.write("Loan Amount: $ " + loan_amount + "<br>");


var range = [12,24,36,48]
for (x=0; x < range.length; x++) {
 
  document.write("Loan for " + range[x] + " months: <br>");
  var monthly_payment = payment(monthly_interest_rate, loan_amount, range[x]).toFixed(2);
   document.write(monthly_payment + "<br>");
  
}
```

```html
<h1>Loan Calculator</h1>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!